# When I say the dua for entering the bathroom should I say that before stepping foot inside or is it ok to say it inside the bathroom

Tags: halal-haram

I am asking this because people usually say it

> isn’t liked to say Allah's name inside the bathroom.

Please Explain. Jazak-Allah

Answer (score -2):

Should be recited before entering the bathroom. Clearly outside the bathroom.

Comment: Ok thank you may Allah bless you

Comment: Would it be possible to quote a scholar who makes this claim?